# PostGIS shapefile and DBF loader 2.0 problem in Windows

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to import a shapefile with polygons into PostGIS (Windows 2008 server). If I import 100 polygons it works fine. If I try to import the full map of 8,100 polygons, about halfway I get an error window "Shape to PostGIS Converter has stopped working".
Problem details (as shown in that window) are:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: shp2pgsql-gui.exe   Application Version:    1.0.0.0   Application
>   Timestamp:    505c6e19   Fault Module Name:   libglib-2.0-0.dll   Fault
>   Module Version:   2.28.8.0   Fault Module Timestamp:  4e253544
>   Exception Code:   40000015   Exception Offset:    0004c2d8   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7   Locale ID:   1033   Additional
>   Information 1:    4a99   Additional Information
>   2:    4a99e4ac53bd5e60be05464c3d1a217e   Additional Information 3:    794a
>   Additional Information 4: 794abc993e1c90d5202dd7b66fde9bb9

Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: check the commit setting. you are probably loading up to much in memory before commit.

Comment: where can I change the commit setting?

Answer (score 1):

The [postgis documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch04.html) shows and example of piping in with sql chapter and section 4.3.1.
[This site](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/shp2pgsql.1.html) also mentions the -D switch for large datasets.
And [here in the postgresql 9.2 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/populate.html) you can find more about the autocommit and checkpoint settings.
Inevitably someone else wil have a better answer.
I am sure many have overcome this in front of you.
Most of my experience is with oracle in this realm.
quick response to the comment made me post something to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and found out that you have to put PostGIS Extention in every single new database which you are creating ;) 
[image]--- so check for postGIS extention just to be sure then the import/export works